# Saving byte sequence when translating from string to bytearray

Tags: python, hex, byte

I get a string that is formed from messages of different types. I'm interested in the message, which before the appearance in the string was in the `format bytearray`, but now comes in the `format str`. For example, I need to translate `001bc5045000043a`, obtained in `str format`, **into byteray format, saving the numbers from this sequence to bytearray**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string of hex digits to a bytearray, assuming two hex digits per byte, use [bytearray.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex):

```
>>> h = '001bc5045000043a'
>>> ba = bytearray.fromhex(h)
>>> ba
bytearray(b'\x00\x1b\xc5\x04P\x00\x04:')
```

Python will represent bytes as the equivalent ASCII character if the byte is in the ASCII range (0-127 / 0 - 0x7f) and the character is printable, hence 0x3a is displayed as ':'

```
>>> chr(int('3a', 16))
':'
```

Comment: and 0x50 is displayed as 'P'?